# How to get all potential orders from a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query and can't quite figure out how to pull up all potential customers for a certain `product_id` from a given `country_id`.  I want a result that has just one record per customer.
My tables are `orders` and `customers`.

```
---customers--
customer_id
country_id
name
---orders---
order_id
product_id
customer_id
```

My current query below gives too many results.  Namely records from other `product_id`'s that are not = 1.  Here is my query:

```
SELECT o.order_id
     , c.name
     , c.customer_id
     , c.country_id
     , o.product_id 
  FROM customers c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN orders o 
    ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id 
 WHERE o.product_id = 1 
    OR c.country_id = 1
```

Some sample results might look like this:

```
order_id    name        customer_id country_id product_id
1           Joe Smith   1           1          1
2           Joe Smith   1           1          2
3           John Doe    2           1          1
4           Kirk Smith  3           1          1
NULL        Ron Rhoden  6           1          1
NULL        Sam Smith   7           1          1
```

For my purposes you can assume that a given customer will only order a given product once.  Notice how I get a result for Joe Smith with `product_id=2`.  I don't want that result in my list.  The Ron Rhoden and Sam Smith results are desirable for my purposes.  How do I filter the `product_id<>1` records but still include all the `country_id=1` records?
Thanks.

Comment: Basically, that a circular argument -- You want the rows with country id = 1 yet you dont.

Comment: No, I want everyone with country_id=1 and for those that have ordered product_id=1 I also want their order_id.

Comment: I always find LEFT JOIN with WHERE... OR really confusing

Comment: Do you want everyone with country_id = 1 AND product_id = 1, or do you want all the records for one specific one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT o.order_id
     , c.name
     , c.customer_id
     , c.country_id
     , o.product_id 
FROM customers c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN orders o ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE o.order_id IN (SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE product_id = 1)
OR c.country_id IN (SELECT customers.country_id FROM customers WHERE product_id = 1)
);
```

Comment: I think you meant the last prodct_id=1 to say country_id=1.  Anyways, I tried that.  It doesn't quite work because I get records from customers who have ordered products other than product_id=1.  Still this is the closest.  See above, I am going with the answer I gave a bit ago.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all customers from country "1" that have ordered product "1".  I would suggest using `exists`:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where c.country_id = 1 and
      exists (select 1
              from orders o
              where o.customer_id = c.customer_id and
                    o.product_id = 1
             );
```

Comment: Well I tried that and it only gives me two records.  With my example data above I want to receive 5 records.  I want everyone with country_code=1 AND for those customers that have an order_id for product_id=1, I also want to see their order_id.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this works.  A bit complicated but I first asked for all the product_id=1 records from orders then did a UNION query and then asked for everyone in customers with country_id=1 but NOT IN the previous product_id=1 results.

SELECT o.order_id, c.name, c.customer_id, c.country_id, o.product_id
FROM customers c   LEFT   JOIN orders o  ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id 
 WHERE o.product_id = 1 UNION SELECT NULL AS order_id, c.name, c.customer_id, c.country_id, NULL AS product_id
 FROM customers c
 WHERE c.country_id = 1 AND c.customer_id NOT IN (SELECT c2.customer_id FROM customers c2 INNER JOIN orders o2 ON c2.customer_id=o2.customer_id WHERE o2.product_id=1)